# ASP .NET VS2010 Contents of an object in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

What's the best way to get the contents of objects into tables in **ASP.NET**?

I've created an `OnButtonClick` event on a page, which then goes and fetches an object with a bunch of variables and one list, how can I get those variables and list to most easily render in a (initially hidden) table?

Should I use this guide? [Table Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Why not use [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx)

Comment: I've seen this too, though I don't know how to get my object which has been created OnButtonClick into the gridview. I can choose source, Object, but can't see the object there. Is there a guide? Do you mean that I should use the "ObjectDataSource", so this would then mean that I've got to change the backend to give me what I need in the front?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581783.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI I ended up using the table class, I made a table maker class that I can throw my objects and entities at and it spits out nicely formatted tables, it was finicky but I felt a better solution than drag and drop programming.

Thanks all!